# How to do a JOIN in SQLAlchemy on 3 tables, where one of them is mapping between other two?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have the following tables:

- `Articles` with fields `article_id`, `title`
- `Tags` with fields `tag_id`, `name`
- `ArticleTags` with fields `article_id`, `tag_id`

And I wish to find all articles that have a given tag. How do I create this complicated join in SQLAlchemy?

In SQL it would look like:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title FROM Articles AS a
JOIN ArticleTags AS at ON a.article_id  = at.article_id
JOIN Tags        AS t  ON at.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.name = 'tag_name'
```

I can't figure out how to do it in SQLAlchemy. I am using `ArticleTags` as "secondary" table only and I can't figure out how to involve it in the JOIN.

Can anyone help?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you set the ForeignKey constraints correctly and created mappers:

```
q = Session.query(Articles).filter(Articles.article_id == ArticleTags.article_id).\
    filter(ArticleTags.tag_id == Tags.tag_id).\
    filter(Tags.name == 'tag_name')
```

If you have setup a Many-to-Many relation it's even more simple:

```
q = Session.query(Articles).filter(Articles.tags.any(name = 'tag_name'))
```

For some more examples for blog-related queries look [here](http://bitbucket.org/ebo/4geeks-blog/src/tip/aurora/controllers/root.py#cl-91).

If you use the sql expression language, it should be straight forward translateable.

Comment: Looks good. But one problem - I haven't mapped `ArticleTags` to any class. I just use `ArticleTags` in the secondary clause in `Articles` and `Tags` mapped classes. Should I map `ArticleTags` to a class then?

Comment: If this does not work, you'll have to give the relevant parts of your model.

Comment: You 2nd solution works but I noticed that it makes a sub-select. Are sub-selects OK?