# Sqlalchemy query foreign keys

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Sqlalchemy question.  If I have a database (sqlite) and three tables `Buyers` `Events`, and `Event_details` like the example below.  The `Event_details`  table has a foreign Key for both the `Buyers` primary key and `Events` primary key.

How can I write a query that would say:

```
If  Buyers.id is in Event_details.buyers_id:
     show me the Events.eventname that matches the Event_details.event_id
```

This is confusing, but I am really trying to understand the connection of a foreign Key and how to query those in a database.  Thank you!

What I presently have is

```
events = db.session.query(Event_details).filter(Event_details.buyer_id == current_user.id)
```

But that just returns the matching event_details name and does not reference the Event.eventname.  Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the answer, I found another post that helped.

[How to do a JOIN in SQLAlchemy on 3 tables, where one of them is mapping between other two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173031/how-to-do-a-join-in-sqlalchemy-on-3-tables-where-one-of-them-is-mapping-between)

My query was

```
events = db.session.query(Events).filter(Events.id == Eventdetails.events_id).filter(Eventdetails.buyer_id == Buyers.id).filter(Buyers.id == current_user.id)
```

Basically saying, get me all the Events
`filter by the Events.id matching Eventdetails.event_id`
`filter this by all Eventdetails.buyer.id that match Buyer.id`
`Finally one match the Buyers.id of the currently logged in user.`